# How to delay a page or sleep tread until the download process or progressbar finished

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-asynctask, android-activity

I have a splash activity like this. This activity display an image for 1.5sec and download the required files from the server if not exists. But I want to delay this page until the download process finished. otherwise just show the image for 1sec as usual. Someone please help.

**Edited:**
Working code.
    public class Splash extends Activity{
        boolean flag = true;

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle LoadingStartPage) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(LoadingStartPage);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        File file_path = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/images/");

        if(file_path.exists()){

        }else{
            String url = "http://example.com";
            new DownloadTask().execute( url );
        }
        Thread timer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    while(flag){
                    sleep(1500);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    Intent openMainActivity = new Intent("com.kabe.example.MAINACTIVITY");
                    startActivity(openMainActivity);
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }


    /**
     * To download and unzip the files from API
     */
    protected ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    //Background task to download and unpack zip file in background.
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Exception> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            showProgress();
        }

        @Override
        protected Exception doInBackground(String... params) {
            String url = (String) params[0];
            try {
                downloadAllAssets(url);
            } catch ( Exception e ) { return e; }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Exception result) {
            dismissProgress();
            flag = false;
            if ( result == null ) { return; }
            // something went wrong, post a message to user - you could use a dialog here or whatever
            Toast.makeText(Splash.this, result.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        }
    }


    //Progress window
    protected void showProgress( ) {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle( R.string.progress_title );
        mProgressDialog.setMessage( getString(R.string.progress_detail) );
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate( true );
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable( false );
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    protected void dismissProgress() {
        // You can't be too careful.
        if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing() && mProgressDialog.getWindow() != null) {
            try {
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            } catch ( IllegalArgumentException ignore ) { ; }
        }
        mProgressDialog = null;
    }

    //Download zip file specified by url, then unzip it to a folder in external storage.
    private void downloadAllAssets( String url ) {
        // Temp folder for holding asset during download
        File zipDir =  ExternalStorage.getSDCacheDir(this, "tmp");
        // File path to store .zip file before unzipping
        File zipFile = new File( zipDir.getPath() + "/temp.zip" );
        // Folder to hold unzipped output
        File outputDir = ExternalStorage.getSDCacheDir( this, "images" );

        try {
            DownloadFile.download( url, zipFile, zipDir );
            unzipFile( zipFile, outputDir );
        }
    }   
}
```

please leave some reputations. Thanks.

Comment: let's use a flag variable, which checks if download is going on, if true sleep again or else move to next activity.

Comment: I couldn't get it. Can you edit this code?

Comment: set a global flag in splash `boolean flag = true;`
in your thread in try `while(flag) sleep(1500)`, in `onPostExecute(){ flag = false }` see if it works !

Comment: Why did you remove the code from the question? It's now completely useless to anyone in a similar situation.

Comment: and yes place the code, it helps others in future !

Comment: sorry accidentally deleted while editing. But got a problem now, if the both files exists it's not starting the mainactivity.

Comment: kabe although it works, but the there may be a problem if the files do exist !, so you may think of moving that code after the thread execution starts ! i.e show the splash i.e the thread, check for files set flag false if they exist, or else download and then set flag false !

Comment: Issues like this are why I recommended a counter: there is no incorrect `false` state, only the desired value and the actual value. If the two are equal, your code will execute. This saves you from having to do a special check in the case where there is no work to do.

Comment: @ChrisHayes accepted ! but there may be `false` state i.e when files have been downloaded, or if they do exist !

Comment: As stated in my answer, my solution is not complete. Any solution to the concurrency problem can have incorrect state; I'm just trying to get Kabe on the right track. The details are easily fixed with a little analysis.

Comment: Thanks ChrisHayes and twntee. Both helped me alot with this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a pretty standard concurrency question. Generally you'd have some flag or counter:

```
int numCompletedDownloads = 0;

// this could be 0, 1 or 2 depending on what files exist locally
int numDownloadsToExecute;
```

Within your try-catch block, you'd have something like this:

```
Thread timer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    while (numCompletedDownloads < numDownloadsToExecute) {
                        sleep(100);
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    Intent openMainActivity = new Intent("com.kabe.sample.MAINACTIVITY");
                    startActivity(openMainActivity);
                }
            }
        };
```

Then, in your DownloadTask, you'd increment the counter.

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Exception result) {
            dismissProgress();
            numCompletedDownloads++;
            // other stuff..
    }
```

The catch, of course, is that concurrent modification of the `numCompletedDownloads` variable is very dangerous and can lead to data races. To avoid that you need to look into some locking mechanism, or some form of atomic operation. Consider perhaps using [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html).

Comment: This doesn't helped that much, it staying always true. But thanks for your answer.

Comment: The code I have posted is meant as a guideline, not a complete working version. Since it sounded like your question stemmed from a fundamental lack of experience with concurrent program, you'd do well to study more on it and try to implement some of the concepts I've described.